# Chi-sqaure type-1-error

Tags: matlab, spss, chi-squared

I have a question about the chi-square test.

I have two between-subject factors, each with two levels (so 4 conditions). Furthermore, I have one dependent variable (qualitative), also consisting of two levels.

Now I want to make pairwise comparisons (so I have 6 chi-sqaure test in total). Is there any way I can control type-1-errors? In the literature I saw they often calculated interaction with a chi-sqaure test. Is this the way to do it, and if so, how do I do it?

I can work with both SPSS and Matlab.

Thank in advance!

Niels

Comment: Maybe this would be more suited to http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks, I was not aware of that forum.